# Kernel update plans for Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, updates, release-management

Is there a site where we can see which kernels we will most likely be getting with upcoming Ubuntu releases?

I'm personally thinking if I should install the 3.13.7.x kernel manually or waiting to get it via update. A site where I can see planned releases would help a lot

Best

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look on DistroWatch (http://distrowatch.com). It might be what you are searching for... Next release of Ubuntu (14.10) will likely be distributed with kernel 3.16.x...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Kernel Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam) wiki page? You should be able to find the information on the blog (with links to logs of the IRC meeting minutes) or on the corresponding mailing list.